# How can you express the following code to a formula

Tags: php, math

Let's say we have a code:

```
<?php
    
    $maximum = 10000;
    $minimum = 5000;
    $size = 10000;
    $step = 0.0001;
    
    $total = 0;
    $counter = $maximum;
    while($counter >= $minimum)
    {
        $counter -= $step;
        $total += $size / $maximum * $step / $counter;
    }
    
    echo "Total is: $total\n";
?>
```

How to express $total variable as a formula? The code acts as an integral where step is infinitesimally small.

Comment: What do you mean with "as a formula"?

Comment: As a mathematical formula. Total is calculated from 3 variables maximum, minimum and size. There should be a way to express it as a formula and to simplify the code by removing "while" cycle.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? This does not look related to programming to me if you are only looking for a formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral is:

```
$total = integral(x from $minimum to $maximum; $size / $maximum / x);
```

`$size / $maximum` is constant and thus simply scales the integral. The closed form of the integral is therefore:

```
$total = $size / $maximum * (log($maximum) - log($minimum))
       = $size / $maximum * log($maximum / $minimum)
```

Assuming that both `$maximum` and `$minimum` are positive.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Big Thanks!